# How to save auth tokens in libgdx for Android and iOS?

Tags: libgdx

I am using Bearer token for authentication in my libgdx based app and I am not 100% sure if I am doing it correctly when it comes to saving the auth token.

So libgdx provides [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) method but I can't anywhere if it is private mode or not. Would it be safe and secure for me to store user auth tokens in libgdx preferences?

Comment: @Squiddie I meant to ask for Android/iOS app only. Updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be save to store the tokens in the preferences as long as the users phone isn't rooted. Because then they have access to the savefiles and every app using root maybe has access too.
So you can use the preferences as long as you encrypt your tokens.

Comment: So is it the same as when you do Android SharedPreference with Mode.Private?